# QGIS Pattern/SVG fill Density control

Tags: symbols, qgis

I have created a single symbol layer style for a polygon layer using a "point pattern fill" layer type. I scatter symbols using horizontal & verical randomize.
I cannot figure out a way to diminish the symbols density towards the polygons edges. I'd like the number of symbols to lower through a buffer zone before the polygon's perimeter, not to he hole area of a polygon.

I don't know if this can be achieved using geometry generator - I have zero knowledge about it. The only thing I managed was a fading effect, but this is not what I was looking for